# Как получить полное содержание файла используя Apache POI?

Tags: java, ms-word, docx, apache-poi

Всем привет! Я пытаюсь прочитать файл .docx с помощью java API Apache POI. Я использую:

```
public static String view(String nameDoc){
    String text = null;
    try{
        XWPFDocument docx = new XWPFDocument(
                new FileInputStream(nameDoc));
        XWPFWordExtractor we = new XWPFWordExtractor(docx);
        text = we.getText();
        we.close();
        docx.close();
    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return text;
}
```

В этом случае я получаю только текст файла, но у меня все файлы разные. В некоторых из них встречается не только текст, но и таблицы, изображения и т.д. Как мне получить полностью содержание файла?

По совету Max использую `wordtohtmlconverter`

```
public static String getDocHtml(String nameDoc){
        String html = null;
        try {
            Document newDocument = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder().newDocument();
            WordToHtmlConverter wordToHtmlConverter = new WordToHtmlConverter(newDocument);
            HWPFDocument doc = new HWPFDocument(new FileInputStream(nameDoc));
            wordToHtmlConverter.processDocument(doc);

            StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
            Transformer transformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
            transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
            transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.ENCODING, "utf-8");
            transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.METHOD, "html");
            transformer.transform(
                    new DOMSource(wordToHtmlConverter.getDocument()),
                    new StreamResult(stringWriter));
            html = stringWriter.toString();
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return html;
    }
```

Отправляю в jsp, но на странице ничего не получаю.
Ошибка: `org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.OfficeXmlFileException: The supplied data appears to be in the Office 2007+ XML. You are calling the part of POI that deals with OLE2 Office Documents. You need to call a different part of POI to process this data (eg XSSF instead of HSSF)`

Answer (score 1):

Советую посмотреть документацию к **XWPFCocument** https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xwpf/usermodel/XWPFDocument.html

В частности там есть метод **getTablesIterator()**, который возврощает итератор по всем таблицам в документе.

Comment: У меня помимо таблиц есть еще и картинки. Я знаю, что есть отдельные методы для вытаскивания картинок и таблиц, а как все это вывести последовательно? Т.е. как получить весь документ в исходном виде и транслировать его например в jsp страницу?

Comment: @Oleg1n Можно использовать метод write, для того, чтобы получить документ как массив байтов [как тут](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10186662/how-can-i-convert-poi-hssfworkbook-to-bytes) и отдать пользователю [вот так](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13989215/how-to-convert-a-byte-into-a-file-with-a-download-dialog-box)

Comment: На основе статей, которые Вы скинули сделал следующее:
`public static byte[] getText(String nameDoc){
        ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        try {
            XWPFDocument docx = new XWPFDocument(new FileInputStream(nameDoc));
            docx.write(byteArrayOutputStream);
            docx.close();
            byteArrayOutputStream.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
         return byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();
    }`

Comment: Теперь мне нужно этот массив передать в jsp страницу, чтобы там сразу транслировалось содержимое документа, без диалога открытия или сохранения.

Comment: Тоесть вы хотите сгенерировать html из word документа? 
В таком случае можно попробовать **WordToHtmlConverter**. 
Вот [пример](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8242407/using-wordtohtmlconverter-converter-in-apache-poi) как его использовать

Comment: Ошибку исправил, WordToHtmlConverter работает, но на страницу транслируется только текст doc файла, картинки и таблицы игнорируются. Это можно как-то исправить?